# Moving objects from one class to another (Java)

Tags: java, class, object, methods, playlist

just wondering how I would go about creating a playlist of song objects (song1, song2, song3, song4) where each object has it's own values (name, artist, filesize, duration). I am not able to use arrays/lists for this program. Just look at the `getSong()` and `addSongToPlaylist()` methods below, I included the other methods just to show the structure of the song objects.

This is my SongDatabase class:

```
public class SongDatabase {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);  
    private Song song1=null, song2=null, song3=null, song4=null;

public void addNewSong() {         
    if (song1 == null) { 
        song1 = getFromUser(); 
    }
    else if (song2 == null) { 
        song2 = getFromUser(); 
    }    
    else if (song3 == null) { 
        song3 = getFromUser(); 
    }
    else if (song4 == null) { 
        song4 = getFromUser(); 
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The database is currently full. Please delete a song before adding a new one."); 
        System.out.println("");
    }    
}

private Song getFromUser() { 
    Song song = new Song(); 

    System.out.println("Name of song:"); 
    song.setName(console.next()); 

    System.out.println("Artist:"); 
    song.setArtist(console.next()); 

    System.out.println("File size (MB):"); 
    song.setFileSize(console.nextInt()); 

    System.out.println("Duration (seconds):"); 
    song.setDuration(console.nextInt()); 

    System.out.println("Song successfully added."); /
    System.out.println("");

    return song; 
}

public Song getSong(int songNumber) { 
    if (songNumber == 1){ 
        return song1; 
    }
    else if (songNumber == 2){ 
        return song2; 
    }
    else if (songNumber == 3){ 
        return song3; 
    }
    else if (songNumber == 4){ 
        return song4; 
    }

    else {
        return song1; 
    }
}
```

And then my menu class:

```
public class Menu {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
    private SongDatabase database = new SongDatabase(); 
    private Playlist playlist = new Playlist(); 
    private int songCount=0; 

private void addSongToPlaylist() { 
  if (songCount <=3) { 

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of the song you'd like to be added to the playlist."); 
    System.out.println("");

    int songNumber; 
    songNumber = console.nextInt(); 

    switch (songNumber) { 
        case 1:
            playlist.setSong(database.getSong(1)); 
            break;
        case 2:
            playlist.setSong(database.getSong(2)); 
            break;
        case 3:
            playlist.setSong(database.getSong(3)); 
            break;
        case 4:
            playlist.setSong(database.getSong(4)); 
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid song number."); 
            break;
    }
    songCount++; 
  }
```

So far, the `addSongToPlaylist()` method should get the song1 object from the `getSong()` method right? But I am unsure how to add these song objects into a playlist in the `Playlist` class. I know I need a method like `public void setSong(parameters?)` but I am unsure how to structure it. Any ideas? Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is our playList class. PlayList class would be having list<Song>

Comment: @HJK, OP says he can't use Lists or collections or arrays.

Comment: You can't move an object, only copy a *reference* to an object.

Comment: So are you not allowed to use lists or are you not able to?

Comment: @MuratK. Not allowed :(

Comment: @Lachie Well, you could create a array of indexes for the selected songs and loop through it. Technically, you are not creating a list for the songs =)

Comment: @Lachie Is your playlist limited to maximum 3 songs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use `List` or `Array` and if your `PlayList` is limited to 3 `Songs` then you can try like this

```
public class Playlist {
    private Song firstSong;
    private Song secondSong;
    private Song thirdSong;

    public void setSong(Song song) {
        if (song != null) {
            if (firstSong == null) {
                firstSong = song;
            } else if (secondSong == null) {
                secondSong = song;
            } else if (thirdSong == null) {
                thirdSong = song;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use any datastructure to hold the list of songs, like array, list, set, map etc.

below is an example code using list.

```
class PlayList {
List<Song> songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

void addSongInList(Song song){
   songList.add(song)l
}

}
```

Comment: "I am not able to use arrays/lists for this program" So I'm kind of stumped.